# During the Data migration with Data Migration Tool, the following error as seen in the screenshot is encountered, Is it safe to ignore it

Tags: magento2, ce-1.9.1.0, data-migration, data-migration-tool

during the Data migration with Data Migration Tool, the following error as seen in the screenshot is encountered. Is it safe to ignore it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File Path:

> /vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml

```
            <attribute type="eav_attribute">attribute_id</attribute>
```

And more refer:-

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/243

And it is safe this process...

Thanks.

Comment: github link has useful information regarding the issue. It is very helpful if you can always provide the link to authentic source to help users get to the solution quicker.

Comment: Let me any query and I have lot of experience of data migration.... Thanks..

Comment: Sure. Could you please share your skype ID?

Comment: https://join.skype.com/invite/a8vGneX5XdBh